# Video lectures on Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for excellent VIDEO lectures on functional analysis.
They should be

(1) in English (2) the video quality and voice is good (3) the lecture should not be presented in boring style

I am very thankful for your suggestions

Comment: Have you checked this [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/functionalanalysis) course or you are looking for something more advanced?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, there is no lecture posted there. Or maybe my firefox has problem

Answer (score 5):

Check this one out:
 http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111105037/

It may be a bit slow but is extensive in content.

Answer (score 5):

Might I recommend the following:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL554B877A872B4F94

Answer (score 4):

Applied Functional Analysis - UCCS MathOnline Course 535

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBC73B96341ECF455

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/739415)

Comment: @C.Falcon: Guess what? A link is exactly what the OP was asking for. Have you also read the question before voting to delete this answer?

Comment: @AlexM. I am really sorry for this mistake, I admit not have read the question before reviewing this answer. I am glad you pointed out my mistake! I was not excepting someone asking for links, I'll be more careful next time!

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest another excellent online course ? I´ve watched most of the videos, and the teacher is very good, building proofs of many theorems.

01325 Mathematics 4 Real Analysis - dtu.dk

Normed vector spaces, Hilbert spaces, bases in Hilbert spaces, basic operator theory, the spaces L^p and l^p, approximation, the Fourier transform, convolution, the sampling theorem, B-splines, special basis functions (e.g, Legendre and Hermite polynomials), an introduction to wavelet theory.

http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/education/01325/    - course website

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjRVZMfYBFMNp7IrHIMft5U_HIikp0T56  - YT

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo4jXE-LdDTTIIIRwqK35CbFJieSJEcVR

The course given by Claudio Landim who is full professer of IMPA.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1762346)

Answer (score 1):

There are two courses on Functional Analysis by a retired professor, S. Kesavan of The Institute of Mathematical Sciences, Chennai, India.

The first course is titled "[Functional Analysis](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/111/106/111106147/)" and covers the following topics (in case the link gets deleted):

1. Normed linear spaces, Continuous linear transformations, examples,
2. Hahn-Banach theorem-extension form, Reflexivity
3. Hahn-Banach theorem-geometric form, Vector-valued integration
4. Baire’s theorem, Principle of uniform boundedness. Application to Fourier series, Open mapping, and closed graph theorems.
5. Annihilators, Complemented subspaces, Unbounded operators, Adjoints.
6. Weak topology. Weak-* topology, Banach-Alaoglu theorem, Reflexive spaces
7. Separable spaces, Uniformly convex spaces, Applications to the calculus of variations
8. $L^p$ spaces. Duality, Riesz representation theorem.
9. $L^p$ spaces on Euclidean domains, Convolutions, Riesz representation theorem
10. Hilbert spaces, Duality, Riesz representation theorem, Application to the calculus of variations, Lax-Milgram lemma, Orthonormal sets
11. Bessel’s inequality, Orthonormal bases, Parseval identity, Abstract Fourier series, Spectrum of an operator
12. Compact operators, Riesz-Fredholm theory, Spectrum of a compact operator, Spectrum of a compact self-adjoint operator

The second course is titled "[Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations](https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in/noc21_ma67/preview)" and is yet to begin (at the time of writing this answer). The topics include:

1. Test functions Distributions, calculus of distributions, support, and singular support of distributions.
2. Convolutions of functions, Convolution of distributions, Fundamental Solutions.
3. Fourier transform, Fourier inversion, Tempered distributions.
4. Sobolev spaces, Definition, Approximation by smooth functions.
5. Extension theorems, Poincare inequality, Imbedding theorems
6. Compactness theorems, Trace theory.
7. Variational problems in Hilbert spaces and Lax-Milgram lemma. Examples of weak formulations of elliptic boundary value problems.
8. Regularity, Galerkin’s method, Maximum principles.
9. Eigenvalue problems, Introduction to the finite element method.
10. Semigroups of operators. Examples, Basic properties, Hille-Yosida theorem.
11. Maximal dissipative operators, Regularity
12. Heat equation, wave equation, Schrodinger equation. Inhomogeneous equations.

Answer (score 0):

I am also quite in search for good video lectures. The Nottingham ones posted by SamM are quite good but the problem, in my opinion, is that the course stays away from measure theory and so there is almost no discussion about $L^p$ spaces. The DTU ones posted by Giovanni are also very good, I think, but they don't do Weak$^*$ topology if I am right.

It is very hard to find a graduate level functional analysis class with video lectures I think.

Comment: Theres one called "Doctorate Program: Functional Analysis" by Dr. Claudio Landim by IMPA, i've found them quite self contained and good on the level of rigor, and it assumes knowledge on measure theory. Theres Weak* Top too on the playlist

Answer (score -1):

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmx4utxjUQD4xJkiHY4pp720LyeCZyEKW

A very engaging course taken by Prof.VittalRao(IISC)