# A good course website for graduate Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It seems not so easy to find a good functional analysis course with problem sets online.

Does anyone have a link to a good graduate course with some good problems?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: I have a copy of Conway's Course in Functional Analysis, and I wanted to know where to begin with this book; and a course outline would have been very helpful.

Comment: On statmathbc.wordpress.com I have notes on Functional Analysis. You can try this.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474696/video-lectures-on-functional-analysis. Personally, I would suggest picking a good book with exercises (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13555/a-book-for-problems-in-functional-analysis) and starting to read Conway from the beginning. After each section you can try to solve the corresponding problems in the second book.